# Limit number of characters of number field

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a numeric field into normal sharepoint online list.

I want to know how can I limit it to 6 numbers. How can I do that user can only type 6 numbers? is that possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect the users to only enter integers you can set the Max limit to 999999 in the Column definition.

And if you want to force users to always enter 6 digits you can set the Min limit to 100000.

EDIT: Updated the limit values, since the Max and Min limits are working as <= and >= instead of > and <.

EDIT 2:
The above approach works with numbers, but it won't recognize leading zeros (e.g. if you want to allow numbers like **000456** to be valid ones). In case you need to cover these scenarios too, you can change the column type to Single line of text and add the following validation formula for the list:

```
=IF(AND(LEN(YourColumnName)=6),(ISNUMBER([YourColumnName]+0)))
```